# Multiple Heroku apps sharing database and queue

Tags: database, performance, heroku, architecture, queue

I have few Heroku apps (all based in the EU data centre) that are using the same database and queue.
I'm sharing them by adding the add-on to one of the apps, and then setting the same environment variable to the rest of the apps and all works fine.

Does it matter to which application I'm adding the add-ons?
Does this affect performance of anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it matter to which application I'm adding the add-ons?

It should not, assuming the applications are all in the same region.

> Does this affect performance of anything else?

It should not, assuming the applications are all in the same region.

Those said, this is a fragile thing to do. For example Heroku Postgres (and probably other 3rd party add-on providers) may change your `DATABASE_URL` in order to maintain high availability in the event of some unforeseen thing (sudden hardware failure, etc).

In that situation, the application that has the add-on attached will be restarted and receive the current `DATABASE_URL`; your other applications will not, and likely crash all over the place.